# UML modeling - How to represent a multi-way inheritance onto a class diagram?

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, modeling, class-diagram

How may this situation be represented onto a class diagram the more elegant (and professional) way (using inheritances ?) ?

An **actor** [class] can be a **physical person** [class] or a **company** [class], but not both.
An actor can be an **inner actor** [class] OR an **external actor** [class], but not both.
An inner actor can be a physical person OR a company, but not both.
An external actor can be a physical person OR a company, but not both.

Of course, here, each said class has its specific attributes, methods and relations with some other classes onto the diagram.

Comment: Does Physical person (and company) can be something else than an actor?

Comment: @Oliver: could you please leave comments if you did not find the answers to your liking?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind multi-inheritance you could consider something like that:

[image: Multi-Inheritance]

(The Inner Actor is displayed tow times to simplify the diagram, it is the same class.)

Comment: This answer misses the requirements of "but not both" everywhere those words occur. For that you need covering and disjointness axioms. (I.e, {complete, disjoint}.)

Comment: Yes, it exactly does. Each instance could be a physical person or a company, but not both. And each instance could be an external actor or an inner actor, but not both.

Comment: This model allows the creation of a `Company` instance that is not an inner or external actor.

Comment: Just forgot to specify the Company as abstract, as other intermediate classes. Tks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant way to represent what you want in UML with the fewest classes:
[image]

Because of the `{complete, disjoint}` constraints, this model requires an instance to be exactly one of `Physical Person` *or* `Company`, while at the same time being exactly one of `Inner Actor` *or* `External Actor`. The instance specification at the bottom shows how to instantiate it.

UML can represent this with no problem. But, how you map it into a programming language is another matter. (And another SO question.) Many languages do not support multiple classification of instances, so you have to hammer a square peg into a round hole.